# AngularJS - triggering $watch synchronously

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am `$watch`ing an object for changes and setting `$scope.changed = true`, however there are circumstances where i want to set it to `false` right after I've altered the data programatically:

```
$scope.$watch('data', function() {
    $scope.changed = true;
}, true);

function loadData(data) {
    $scope.data = data;

    // I want to run $scope.$apply() here so the $watch is triggered
    // before changed is set back to false
    $scope.$apply();

    $scope.changed = false;
}

// in DOM:
<div ng-click="loadData(newData)">
```

If I run `loadData` manually using a non-angular event it works fine (of course `$apply`ing the scope again afterwards), but if I run it from something like the above `ngClick` then it errors out with "$apply already in progress".

Using a `$timeout` works in most circumstances, but there are some places where I really want it to happen synchronously.

```
function loadData(data) {
    $scope.data = data;
    // what I want to avoid:
    $timeout(function() {
        $scope.changed = false;
    })
}
```

Is it possible to apply scope changes synchronously, or am I doing change handling wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're not doing something really special you can use `angular.equals` to check if two objects are equal. Use that in combination with `angular.copy` so you have a copy of the original data.

```
$scope.isDirty = function () {
    return !angular.equals(initialData, $scope.data);
}
```

<kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/QqIp5UrVYvmr5QimUln9?p=preview)</kbd>

Doing it this way you don't need to worry about the order of your `$watch` functions and the code will be much easier to understand.

Performance wise, this might be heavier though. You could optimize it by changing so that isDirty only is changed when the data is changed.

Comment: Thanks, works well and after fiddling with it a bit the overhead shouldn't be too bad. I modified it a so it doesn't need to run the comparison after the data has changed the first time since `changed` was reset. Thankfully I don't need to know if it returns to its original state. [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/OI2zobbwsm0NKgqlXj6v?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

`ngclick` will occupy the `$apply` handler, so you can't run process which need `$apply` in an event handler function,just `$timeout` all action in a function like :

```
function loadData(data){
    $timeout(function(){
        $scope.data = data;
        $scope.$apply();
        $scope.changed = false;
    });
}
```

Try this, but not tested...

Comment: I'd like to do it all synchronously if possible, setting a `$timeout` is my current workaround but working with asynchronous operations tends to add complexity.

Comment: @DeathCarrot I think function(){#code#} and function(){$timeout(function(){#code#})} is nearly the same, except running before or after the endpoint of click event.You need to ensure the synchronism of #code# and endpoint of click event?

Comment: In some cases the equivalent of the loadData function is far down the call stack, the original call of which can be called from several places, some of which are likely deep in someone else's code. There can also be other timeouts which depend on the value of `changed` being valid, which it won't be between the `$watch` and `$timeout`. Of course you can wrap the code that uses `changed` in two `$timeout`s but that eventually starts getting a bit tedious.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a second `$scope` variable to keep track of whether the change came from a particular function and based on that, enable the `$scope.changed` variable assignment in your `$watch`.

Add a variable to serve as a marker in your `loadData()` function.  In this case, we'll call it `$scope.explicitChange`:

```
function loadData(data) {
    $scope.data = data;

    // I want to run $scope.$apply() here so the $watch is triggered
    // before changed is set back to false
    $scope.$apply();

    $scope.changed = false;
    $scope.explicitChange = true;
}
```

Check if `$scope.explicitChange` has been set in your `$watch`:

```
$scope.$watch('data', function(){
    if(!$scope.explicitChange){
        $scope.changed = true;
    }
    else{
        // Reset $scope.explicitChange
        $scope.explicitChange = false;
    }
}, true);
```